# Removing stopwords,but should return as a line

Tags: python

My question may appear silly. But as I am a rookie in Python , help me out.

I have to pass a line to a stopword removal function. It works fine. But my problem is return of the function is appending the words. I want it as like follows:

```
line = " I am feeling good , but I cant talk"
```

Let `"I,but,cant"` are stopwords.

After passing to the function , my output should be as `"am feeling good , talk"`.
What I a getting now is `[['am','feeling','good','talk']]`.

Help me.

Comment: Can you show us your attempt? We might figure out your mistake.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: @aIKid asked you to show the code not to format your question!!!

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades, actually, it wasn't the OP who formatted the question.

Comment: @aIKid: Joke of the day! I started laughing....

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades What?

Comment: @aIKid: I laughed at myself for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades Okay that's genius, i wish i can be like that all the time. Life's gonna be fun. Hahaha

Answer (score 0):

To get that list as a string, you can do:

```
>>> out = [['am','feeling','good','talk']]
>>> " ".join(out[0])
'am feeling good talk'
>>>
```

However, I think this is more what you want:

```
>>> line = " I am feeling good , but I cant talk"
>>> [word for word in line.split() if word not in ("I", "but", "cant")]
['am', 'feeling', 'good', ',', 'talk']
>>> lst = [word for word in line.split() if word not in ("I", "but", "cant")]
>>> " ".join(lst)
'am feeling good , talk'
>>>
```

Important parts here are [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), and a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 0):

```
line = " I am feeling good , but I cant talk"
stop_words={'I','but','cant'}
li=[word for word in line.split() if word not in stop_words] 
print li
# prints ['am', 'feeling', 'good', ',', 'talk']
print ' '.join(li)
# prints 'am feeling good , talk'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using list comprehension:

```
def my_function(line, stopwords):
    return [word for word in line.split() if word not in stopwords]

stopwords = ['i', 'but', 'cant']
line = " I am feeling good , but I cant talk"
my_function(line, stopwords)
```

Which is roughly equal to this piece of code below:

```
def my_function(line, stopwords):
        result = []
        for i in line.split(): #loop through the lines
        if i not in stopwords: #Check if the words are included in stopwords
            result.append(i)
```

Result:

```
['am', 'feeling', 'good,', 'talk']
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Guys... I will sure check it out now.

I have to read every line of a text and pass it to the stopword function.
I will check it out now itself.

Thanks alot guys.

Comment: You're very welcome, sarath! If this answers your current question, please accept it :)

Comment: Tips: use the `with` statement when opening a file, so you don't have to manually close it later.